# ActionView::TemplateMissing error in Rails 4 when rendering shared errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm learning Rails and am implementing an app for which I decided to go through the [Site Point tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/magical-authentication-sorcery/).

According to it, I've done the following in `apps/views/users/new.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/errors', object: @user %>  #=> error
    <div class="form-group">
       <%= f.label :name %>
       <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: 'Your display name', class: 'form-control', required: true %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

But I'm getting

> `ActionController:MissingTemplate` in `Users#new`

How can I get rid of it? I've posted the full trace [here](http://pastebin.com/MzkSVzSP)

Comment: You didn't provide full error message, so it's only guess: Do you have `views/shared/errors.html.erb` template?

Comment: @MarekLipka no, I don't have that. Also, I've pasted full trace in the question.

Comment: That's why you have an error, exactly as message says.

Comment: @MarekLipka but the tutorial provided no hints of it being created. What should I put in there?

Comment: Error messages, probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial you're following assumes you have an `_errors.html.erb` file in the `app/views/shared` directory.

```
<%= render 'shared/errors', object: @user %>
```

That line of code is trying to render that partial and pass `@user` which will be used in the partial.

If you want to remove that error then remove that line of code. If you want to display those errors then create the relevant file and read up on how to [display errors in the view](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#displaying-validation-errors-in-views).

Comment: how is that possible to say without the codes and logs

Comment: @argentum47 nope. I figured it out. It was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <ol>
      <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li class="alert alert-danger"><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ol>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Put this in your `app/views/shared/_errors.html.erb`

Comment: I'm getting `undefined local variable or method 'obj' for #<#<Class:0x55189e0>:0x5d01d28>` What should I do?

Comment: sorry, my mistake... check new answer

Comment: It seems I have to use the variable `@user` instead of `object`.

Comment: object: @user means, you have access to object inside your partial... its  a local variable thing..

Comment: Thanks, I got it. But, sorry, I've accepted the other answer as his link helped me immediately.

Comment: lol,  I don't care about that.. this is a community where people help selflessly (other than when downvote, I don't feel bad about votes :D)